# Usar xls como fonte de dados

Tags: php, mysql, csv

tenho várias planilhas com dados. Eles tem a primeira coluna como nome da tabela.

1) Dá pra formatar um CSV com a primeira coluna como nome da tabela, em vez de normalmente usar a primeira linha como nome da coluna?

2) Dá pra ler cada uma das planilhas como fonte de dados, em vez de mysql?

Comment: 1 - Sim. 
2 - Sim.

Comment: @JorgeB., seria bom justificar as respostas com apoio na documentação, e fornecer exemplos.

Comment: @FellipeSoares eu só comentei, não respondi. De qualquer forma é isso que ele pergunta. Se dá, não como fazer.

Comment: @JorgeB. Desculpe, o que eu quis dizer é: "Seria bom 'fornecer uma resposta' com apoio na documentação, e fornecer exemplos. =)